# Matlab crashes when using parfor

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-20.04

I run the following code in parallel, but Matlab crashed.

```
n = 200;
A = 5000;
a = zeros(1,n);
parfor i = 1:n
     a(i) = max(abs(eig(rand(A))));
end
```

The validated information of my Matlab cluster

[image]

I am new to Ubuntu. I have raised the limit of open files to try to fix the error but fail as well.

[image]

The crashed message of Matlab.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to run the code with a smaller value for `A`? This sounds like an issue in MATLAB, you should send a bug report to The MathWorks.

Comment: It works with a small value of A, such as A = 500. @CrisLuengo  And it can run the code with less CPU, say, 12 workers

Comment: Are these local workers or distributed on a cluster? If local, why would you want to run 40 copies of MATLAB on one machine? Did you try setting up your parallel pool to be tread-based? They have more limitations, but would probably be good for your test case at least.

Comment: They are local workers. It is just a parfor example from MathWorks. I am still getting the same error when running other parfor examples. @CrisLuengo

Comment: Each local worker is a separate instance of MATLAB. It is unlikely that you can run 40 instances of MATLAB simultaneously on your machine, no matter how much memory you have. Try the thread-based parallelism instead. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html